# How to use tf.gather in combination with tf.where

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following is not working due to the shape of `tf.where()`. Is there a nice way to fix this?

I want the values of `tensor_y` where `tensor_x` fulfills a condition (e.g. == value ). Important, the tensors have `batch_dims = 1`.

```
tensor_x = tf.random.uniform(shape=[2, 10], minval=-1, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)
tensor_y = tf.random.uniform(shape=[2, 10], minval=-1, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)
trues = tf.where(tensor_y ==1)


new_tensor = tf.gather(tensor_y, axis=-1, indices = trues,batch_dims=1)
```

What I am doing now works*, but it is not so efficient I think:

```
new_tensor = tf.stack([tf.gather(tensor_y[i,:], tf.where(tensor_x[i,:] == 1)) for i in range(tensor_x.shape[0])])
```

*sometimes (I don't know under which conditions) I get his error:

Shapes of all inputs must match: `values[0].shape = [3,1] != values[1].shape = [6,1] [Op:Pack] name: stack`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
tensor_x = tf.random.uniform(shape=[2, 10], minval=-1, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)
tensor_y = tf.random.uniform(shape=[2, 10], minval=-1, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)

new_tensor = tensor_y[(tensor_x==1)]
```

Comment: This is working in a tensorflow environment. But outside of this environment, I get this error:  `Value passed to parameter 'begin' has DataType bool not in list of allowed values: int32, int64`